# python: Split string by last occurrence seems to delete it rather then split it

Tags: python, string

I am using the following code to first check if there to the '(' in the string.
If so i want to split the string into two like the below example

```
['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+)', '1m4f Standard']
['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+) (1m4f50y)', '1m4f Standard','(1m4f50y)']
```

but for some reason if I run the following code:

```
if details[1].count('(') == 2:
            details = details[1].rsplit('(', 1)
```

i get

```
['(Class 6)', ['(0-60, 4yo+)', '1m4f50y)'], '1m4f Standard']`
```

when i would like

```
['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+)', '1m4f Standard','(1m4f50y)']
```

Comment: When you split something, you consume whatever you split it with. In this case, the '(' character

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis tbh its ok that it deletes the ( as i will be deleting those anyway to clear it up ... im just looking to shift the distance on it own so i can cleanly add it to my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsplit()` returns a list, which you put into `details`. If you take the first element `[0]` of that list and put it into the element you were taking data from `details[1]` you should get what you expect.

```
if details[1].count('(') == 2:
    splitdata = details[1].rsplit('(', 1)
    details[1] = splitdata[0]
    details.extend(splitdata[1:])
```

Comment: Doing that just gives me (0-60, 4yo+)

Comment: gave that aga and it seems to just delete it   ['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+)', '1m4f Standard'] is the new output

Comment: Ah you want to append the rest? That wasn't super clear in your question... anyways, check the update

Answer (score 0):

Is this kinda what you're trying to do?

```
deets = [
    ['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+) (1m4f50y)', '1m4f Standard', '(1m4f50y)']
]

def separate_tuples(details: list) -> list:

    # Loop over each string in the list, but also get it's index
    for index, string in enumerate(details):

        # If the string has more than one tuple, remove it,
        if string.count('(') == 2:
            details.remove(string)

            # but keep using the removed string for the following:
            # separate it into parts
            for part in string.split(')', 1):
                # clear whitespace from either side
                part = part.strip()

                # if the part already exists in the list, get rid of the duplicate
                if part in details:
                    details.remove(part)

                # if the part doesn't end in a paren, add one and insert it at the current index
                # otherwise, just add the part with no extras
                details.insert(index, part + ')' if not part.endswith(')') else part)

            # Move the current item to the back of the list
            details.append(details.pop(index))

    return details


for deet in deets:
    print(separate_tuples(deet))
```

Output

```
['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+)', '1m4f Standard', '(1m4f50y)']
```

Comment: Yes!
is it possible to delete the 'old' sting so it looks like
`details = ['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+) ', '1m4f Standard','(1m4f50y)'] (also could you explain what the code is doing :) )

Comment: Added some comments for you and made it into a function. You can test it on multiple lists of strings

Comment: My input is `['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+) (1m4f50y)', '1m4f Standard','(1m4f50y)']` and my putput need to be `['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+) ', '1m4f Standard', '(1m4f50y)']`